# Migrating from FBConnect to Facebook sdk

Tags: ios, facebook

I would like to migrate from fbconnect to facebook sdk. My application is already running on fbconnect. Can i simply delete just delete the fbconnect files(such as FB request, Facebook, FBDialog) files and simply add Facebook SDK framework in?

When I do that, i get errors like:

1)No Facebook.h, No FBDialog.h , NO FBRequest.h so on...

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply replacing the framework with previous FBConnect files will not work. They are now using "FBSession" concept for logging in and changed posting methods also.

So it would be better for you to follow the document [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/).